# Arrangements of $5$ A's,$7$ B's and $4$ C's to form a $16$ letter word so that there are at least $3$ $CA$ pairs occurring in the word.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

In how many ways can we arrange $5$ A's,$7$ B's and $4$ C's to form a $16$ letter word so that there are at least $3$ $CA$ pairs occurring in the word.(In other words there are at least $3$ occurrences of a $C$ immediately followed by an $A$)

My Attempt:
I get different answers

**Method 1:**

I arrange the following:$(CA),(CA),(CA),C,A,A,B,B,B,B,B,B,B$ in $$\frac{(13)!}{3!2!7!}=102960$$ways.

**Method 2:**

Pairing the four C's with four A's we can arrange the 4 CA's,1 A and 7 B's in$$\frac{12!}{4!1!7!}=3960$$ ways. Now we will count the arrangements with exactly 3 CA's. We place 3 CA's,1 C and 7 B's in a row in $$\frac{11!}{3!1!7!}=1320$$ways. Off the 12 gaps that are formed we need to choose 2 out of 11(leaving out the gap just after C) o place the 2 A's which can be done in $$\binom{11+2-1}{2}=66$$ways. Thus the number of arrangements with exactly 3 CA's is$$1320\times 66=87120$$So total number of arrangements with at least three occurrences of CA is $$87120+3960=91080$$

**So which cases are getting over counted.**

Comment: Here is one example - in the first method, what happens when you have $(CA) \ B \ C \ A $ vs $C \ A \ B \ (CA)$? They are not really different.